# wp_nav_menu always falls back to a menu

Tags: menus, navigation

hey all,
i'm writing an automated function that generates a menu from a function. it calls wp_nav_menu on each item from an array, because i want this to be dynamic. the problem is, no matter how i set it, if the menu doesn't exist, wp_nav_menu is generating a menu, eg the 'default'. here is my code (items is just a set of strings):

```
for($i=0;$i<count($items);$i++) {

    $themenu=$items[$i];

    $mymenu = wp_nav_menu(array(
            'menu' => $themenu,
            'menu_class' => 'mymenu',
            'container' => 'false',
            'fallback_cb' => 'false',
            'echo' => false
            )
        );  

    echo $themenu;

    }
```

i know its partially working, because if $themenu exists, it shows the correct one. but if it doesn't, it'll just show any menu! not just annoying, but also actively breaks the user experience.

Comment: Try to set `'fallback_cb' => ''`

Comment: i tried that, no luck.

Comment: can you show more of your code so we could see whats causing this? also you can try to create a stub function that does nothing and use that as you fallback.

Comment: sure, edited above to reflect the whole loop... nothing super complicated

Comment: `size($items)`? Do you mean `count($items)`? Or did you define a `size()` function elsewhere?

Comment: sorry its count, you're right

Answer (score 8):

`wp_nav_menu()` indeed tries a lot to provide you with a menu, and `fallback_cb` is only executed when nothing else works. [From the code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L148):

- If `menu` is provided and refers to an existing menu (looked up via [`wp_get_nav_menu_object()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-includes/nav-menu.php#L10), which accepts an id, slug or name), this will be the menu
- Otherwise, if `theme_location` is set to a registered menu location, this will be passed to `wp_get_nav_menu_object()`
- Otherwise, WordPress will search for the first existing menu that has items and use that
- Otherwise, `fallback_cb` is called, which by default is `wp_page_menu`, which is a menu of all the pages

So if you only want to use the `menu` argument, you should test this yourself by calling `wp_get_nav_menu_object()`. Only if this returns something you should call `wp_nav_menu()`.

Comment: jan, thats the test i was looking for! undocumented, that is. thanks.

Comment: @yonation: Well, the code is documentation too :-)

Comment: I'm having the same problem but I don't follow this answer. Do you mind sharing your code?

Comment: This was extremely helpful- WP kept forcing a fallback menu until I finally just wrapped the `wp_nav_menu()` call in an `if ( wp_get_nav_menu_object($id) ) {...}` to nullify any chance of a fallback- thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your echo inside of a `has_nav_menu()` conditional:

```
for($i=0;$i<size($items);$i++) {

    $themenu=$items[$i];

    $mymenu = wp_nav_menu(array(
            'menu' => $themenu,
            'menu_class' => 'mymenu',
            'container' => 'false',
            'fallback_cb' => 'false',
            'echo' => false
            )
        );  

    if ( has_nav_menu( $themenu ) ) echo $themenu;

    }
```

(If I'm following your code correctly...)

Comment: hi chip thanks for the suggestion, but [has_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_nav_menu) only refers to menu *location* not slug/name.  i am not working with locations for this particular theme, so we are back at the beginning. it amazes me there is no has_nav_menu_name or something...

Answer (score 1):

From the Codex entry for [wp_nav_menu()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu):

> $fallback_cb (string) (optional) If
>   the menu doesn't exist, the fallback
>   function to use. **Set to false for no
>   fallback.** Default: wp_page_menu

So have you tried passing `'fallback_cb' => false`?

EDIT:

As per the comment below, `'fallback_cb' => 'false'` is telling `wp_nav_menu()` to fallback to a function called `false()`, and since this function doesn't exist, it falls back to its normal fallback, `wp_page_menu()`. So, use `'fallback_cb' => false` (i.e. a *boolean* value, rather than a *string* value).

Comment: Er, I guess you did. Hmm... maybe it needs to be `false`, rather than `'false'`? Grasping at straws here.

Comment: @Chip Bennett Yes, `'false'` refers to an impossible function `false()` while just `false` is a boolean value.

Comment: chip and toscho, thanks for the help. i see the difference but both false and 'false' still give me the default menu. i think the problem lies in the core include (i've been tooling around there) - fallback is used if the LOCATION isn't found, not if the menu. if the menu isn't found, then it does whatever the hell it wants, which is a really weird reaction.  basically i need to - but don't want, for obvious upgrade & other reasons - edit wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php.

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't register/use a `theme_location` for each of these dynamic menus?

Comment: no reason for me personally, though a)i see it as an extra unnecessary step and b)i'm a web dev and trying to think of this as the enduser would; if they want to create a new submenu that would automatically attach to existing elements, i want it as dynamic as possible. theme_location makes that flow impossible. frankly i do not for the life of me get why they wouldn't let you fallback on NO menu rather than a default, seems like a big error.

Comment: It's not really an "unnecessary step"; it can just be another function in functions.php, in which you use the same for loop is used to generate the `register_nav_menus()` function output - which would then allow you to create menus accordingly, populate them dynamically, and display them only if they exist.

Comment: Chip, that's interesting. I'll do that and report back. Thanks much.